# Help creating a image servlet using Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-mvc

I am creating a JSF application and I have a bunch of images (avatars) stored in my DB as blobs. I am trying to create a servlet so I can call a url such as "/imageServlet?123 and it will call my servlet pass the 123 as the id etc etc and output the Stream.

I am very new to Spring but I did some reading and it looks like I need to use the MVC but am confused how what the class and method declarations need to look like. Do I need to use the @Controller annotation? I really just need a decent example so I can follow it and know where to put my code.

Currently my class is declared like this

```
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    ...
    @Override 
    protected void doGet(HttpServlet request, HttpServletResponse respose) {
      ...
    }
}
```

I am assuming this is wrong but I cant find any examples of how to do this in Spring. A little guidance would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: First this question: what exactly do you need Spring for in the servlet?

Comment: I don't know, I really do not know anything that is required to do this, I just read that someone used Spring for this somewhere and I thought I would need to also.

Comment: Bozho already covered it. Try not to overcomplicate things. If you don't need spring managed beans, then just don't try it the hard way :)

Comment: I was not trying to do it the hard way, I was just trying to do it the right way. If spring is not the right way to do it then I misunderstood. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need to access the spring context, you can safely have a servlet like the one you showed. You will just have to use `request.getParameter("id")` (with a url of type `/imageServlet?id=123`).

If you, however, need to access spring beans, so that you can get the user corresponding to passed id, then you can have a `@Controller` with a method like:

```
@RequestMapping("/image/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public byte[] getImage(@PathVariable int id) {
     // load the image into a byte array and return it
}
```